# Automatic facebook wall post, access token keep expire

Tags: post, cron, facebook-access-token, facebook-wall

I have to automatic post on my facebook page wall. So far so good... but the access token keep expire. I did the automatic post with my App and with the Graph Explore and I have the same problem with both.

To post on facebook wall, I create a Cron job on my server, but after some hours the access token expire and I have to create a new one every time manually, and it's not the idea of automatic service :)

I read most of answers here with similar problem of mine, but can't find the answer already.

**So, I just need a way to get a new access token, every time the cronjob call my php file.**

Answer (score 1):

You could have the cron job email you an authorization link a day or two before the token expires. Using [exchange_token](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token) you can get a 60-day token, so you only have to re-authorize it every other month.